# When to throw an exception and when to handle issue elegantly

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns

Lets say I have this code:

```
public void MyMethod(string Data, List<string> InputData)
{
  //I would assume throwing an exception for nulls would be correct
  if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Data) || InputData == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("Oops");

  if (InputData.Count == 0) 
    //throw exception or use event to raise a problem
    //throw Exception("Empty List")
    //if (DisplayError != null)
    //  DisplayError("Empty List");
}
```

Now having a empty list is not an exceptional problem so I should cope with it elegantly. One way is to raise an event to notify the problem. Just makes me wonder why I dont just raise the event if the arguments are null.

What is the best practice in this type of issue?

**EventHandler Example:**

```
public class MyOtherClass
{
  public event Action<string,List<string>> ItFired;

  public void DoSomething()
  {
     if(ItFired != null)
       ItFired(myString, myList);
  }
}

public class AnotherClass
{
     public void DoSomething()
     {
           var otherclass = new MyOtherClass();
           var myClass = new MyClass();

           otherClass.ItFired += myClass.MyMethod;
     }

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is better to detect for exceptions and throw them or just let runtime throw them?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9976870/is-better-to-detect-for-exceptions-and-throw-them-or-just-let-runtime-throw-them)

Comment: @Steve Gates: when you think you have to cope with the case of an empty list as a special case, then *it is* an exceptional problem. Of course, there may be reasons why you want to use events instead of exceptions here either, for example, when MyMethod is itself an event handler (or part of it) and shall not throw any exceptions. But arguing about this because of performance reasons - when you don't face any real performance problems - is almost always a completely wrong approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If an `empty list` *is not exceptional problem* **do not raise exception** in that case. `Exceptions` are for exceptional cases. In this case you can just return some `boolean` (say) value, that indicates that function is not executed.

If for the `caller` of that function that would be an exceptional case, then it (caller) will raise an exception.

Good luck.

Comment: The method does not return anything, its an event handler. I'm defining exceptional in the terms of nulls etc. If I do checks for empty lists this is not exception just a pain otherwise I'd be throwing exceptions all over the place if something wasn't quite right or should I be throwing all these exceptions?

Comment: +1 It's also worth noting that exceptions for controlling regular program flow are quite slow - an oft overlooked performance issue that you tend not to care about when you are throwing them for actual problems.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth Very true which is why I tend to use events

Comment: @SteveJobs: from the function I see it doesn't seems to be a *standart* event handler. So may be you can change a *delegate* of it. In this case a function handles that event will be able to communicate to one who raised an event about a failure/sucess. That could be some custom *event argument* (just example)

Comment: @Steve Gates: if the "empty list" is not an exceptional case - why is it a problem at all which needs error displaying or event notification? Can `MyMethod` not handle lists of arbitrary sizes n, where n=0 is no special case?

Comment: @Tigran Don't suppose you could supply some sample code? Its an event handler in the sense that a another class with an event with Action<string, List<string>> delgate is called

Comment: @DocBrown If the list is zero I cannot proceed so maybe this defines it as an exceptional case?

Comment: @Steve Gates: see my comment above below your question.

Comment: @Tigran I assume you mean using Func instead of Action?

Comment: @SteveGates: so it *sounds* to me (hope understood correctly) that it's even easier. You call a function within another function. So just manage the return value between them. Am I wrong?

Comment: @SteveGates: you have 2 options, imo: 1) Use a function instead of Action<T>, so can return a value. 2) Add an *out* parameter to Action<string,List<string>, out SomeType result>>.